# SwiftUI Preview launches macOS App from root

Tags: swiftui, simulator, preview

I can successfully launch the following preview.

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}

struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUIView()
    }
}
```

But the entire macOS App also launches as an independent external simulator. It's very annoying because it sits on top of Xcode and any hot reload event pushes it back in front of Xcode.

Any help on how to prevent this would be appreciated.

- Xcode 14.1 (14B47b)
- macOS 13.0 (22A380)

Comment: You could use `selectable` preview instead of `live` preview. If you only care about layout then `selectable` preview is enough. The buttons are on the bottom left of the canvas (preview screen).

Comment: It's already on that setting.

Comment: `selectable` preview would show the preview in the same canvas and not in a different window, can you post a screenshot of what you are see along with the buttons selected?

Comment: Do you resolve the issues?

Comment: @NikolaiNagornyi No